# Arguments passed to nodejs script are are empty according to process.argv

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs script where I am passing some arguments. 
The problem is that nodejs does not seem to pick this arguments. T
I have done this many times before, but never run into an issue. 
Below is the code :

```
var StartConnect = require('./sourceConnect');

console.log("process.argv : " + JSON.stringify(process.argv))
var args = process.argv.splice(2);

console.log("args : " + JSON.stringify(args))

if(args.length < 1) {
    console.log("usage: node " + process.argv[1] + " <configuration> 
");

process.exit(0);
}
var startCon = new StartConnect(args);
startCon.masterProc();
```

When I run it as :

```
bash-3.2$ node start.js config.json 
process.argv : ["/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node"]
args : []
usage: node undefined <configuration>
```

Any ides why the arguments array would be empty save for the node runtime? This is so weird and frustrating!

Comment: Is sourceConnect doing anything with argvs?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is this: `Array.prototype.splice` does not do what you think. When you call it, it expects its arguments to be `array.splice(index, count, ...newItems)`, and it does this at a high level:

1. Remove at most `count` items from `array`, starting at `index`, and store the removed items in a new array.
2. Insert `newItems` into `array` starting at `index`.
3. Return the new array created in step 1.

You can find more details on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), where it goes in a bit more detail.

---

Instead, try using `Array.prototype.slice`. If you changed `splice` to `slice` in your code, it'd do exactly what you want. You can find more details on that particular method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: would using `slice` fix this?